# Has Emacs same tool as "screen" in Linux?

Tags: display

Linux Ubuntu, Emacs 26.1

I use tool "`screen`" in Linux. It's very comfortable. 
Has Emacs any some kind of tool?

Comment: Why do you need it? What do you want to run in the screen inside Emacs?

Comment: See also this: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsScreen

Comment: Or use this package : ElScreen:  https://github.com/knu/elscreen

Comment: The thing I considered `screen` most useful for was re-connecting to a remote session from somewhere else, and Emacs provides for that if you run it as a server, as you can `ssh` from anywhere to the host running the server, and then reconnect to that Emacs session with `emacsclient`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, Emacs *is* that tool. Let me illustrate.  In the following `Ctrl + x` is denoted as `C-x` and `Alt + x` is denoted as `M-x` (this is the standard Emacs notation).

---

Open a new instance of Emacs.  You can create splits, similarly to `screen`.  To create a vertical split, press `C-x 3`.  To create a horizontal split, press `C-x 2`.  Do that and your Emacs should look like this:

[image: Emacs after doing <code>C-x 2 C-x 3</code>]

Now, if you wanted to have separate terminal windows there are several options.  Emacs comes with several terminal emulators: `eshell`, `shell`, and `term`. You could open a term with `M-x shell`<sup>1</sup>.  For me, that opened a terminal instance in the second split:

[image: Opening a shell]

You can go to another split with `C-x o`.  You could open another terminal instance if you wanted there.  Or you could edit a document.  Whatever your heart desires!

---

Hopefully you can see how Emacs itself functions as a terminal multiplexer.

I highly recommend reading the Emacs tutorial.  To access it, simply open a new session of Emacs and press `<RET>`.  People say learning Emacs is hard, but it's as simple as opening Emacs and pressing Enter!

[image: How to access the Emacs tutorial]

<sup>1</sup> The `term` command is finicky when using Windows, which I am.  So, I use `shell` here.

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/knu/elscreen

Comment: To use `elscreen`, you'll need to create a file `init.el` in your `~/.emacs.d` directory.  In that file, you will need to initialize packages. Put this code on one line: `(package-initialize)`.  Then you'll need to add a third-party repository: `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)`.  To run these, do `M-x eval-b`. That should re-index the repository.  Now, you can do `M-x list-packages`. Search for `elscreen`.  As long as your cursor is on that line, press `i` to mark it for install and press `x` to install it.  Once installed, do `M-x elscreen-start`

Comment: If that's what you needed, let me know and I will update my answer to reflect that.  In the meantime you may find this article about installing Emacs packages helpful: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InstallingPackages

Comment: For now , Emacs is enough for me. If , for some reasons, I will be need screen session manager I will install elscreen.